# How to integrate JIRA with our own AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, jira

I want to integrate JIRA with my own application, so that I can perform operations like:

- Create a ticket
- Delete a ticket

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [NPM dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-connector). Hope this helps

1. Install with npm:

> $ npm install jira-connector

2. Retrieve an issue from Jira, and print its summary to the console.

> ```
> // ES5
> var JiraClient = require('jira-connector');
>
> // ES6 or Typescript
> import JiraClient from 'jira-connector';
>
> // Initialize
> var jira = new JiraClient({
>     host: 'jenjinstudios.atlassian.net',
>     strictSSL: true // One of optional parameters
> });
>
> // ES5
> jira.issue.getIssue({
>     issueKey: 'JWR-19'
> }, function(error, issue) {
>     console.log(issue.fields.summary);
> });
>
> // ES6
> jira.issue.getIssue(issueKey: 'JWR-19')
>     .then(issue => {
>         console.log(issue.fields.summary);
>     })
>     .catch(error => throw error);
>
> // ES8 or Typescript. NodeJS 7.6.0 or higher
> const issue = await jira.issue.getIssue({ issueKey: 'JWR-19' });
> ```

First, the JiraApi class is imported from the jira-connector module. This class provides access to the Jira REST endpoints, organized into related classes.

The issue property of the JiraApi class is used to retrieve and modify Jira Issues.